# How to only include a single (first) duplicate row in a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My issue here is the revenue field, where the value has been duplicated three times. I need a select query which excludes two of the duplicate values but retains a single row. The query must include the non duplicates rows as well.

```
timeStamp             fieldValue          prevValue     newValue
17/11/2017 11:41      Revenue             £0.00         £12,000.00
17/11/2017 11:41      Revenue             £0.00         £12,000.00
17/11/2017 11:41      Revenue             £0.00         £12,000.00
17/11/2017 11:42      Revenue             £0.00         £16,000.00
17/11/2017 11:42      Revenue             £0.00         £16,000.00
17/11/2017 11:42      Revenue             £0.00         £16,000.00
17/11/2017 11:42      Revenue             £16,000.00      £18,000.00
17/11/2017 11:42      Revenue             £18,000.00      £16,000.00
17/11/2017 11:42      Status              Open          Won
17/11/2017 11:42      Est. Close Date     24/11/2017      21/12/2017
17/11/2017 18:17      Est. Close Date     19/01/2018      16/02/2018
17/11/2017 18:17      Revenue             £16,000.00      £18,000.00
17/11/2017 18:18      Revenue             £18,000.00      £16,000.00
17/11/2017 18:18      Status              Open          Won
17/11/2017 14:35      Est. Close Date     24/11/2017      21/12/2017
20/11/2017 10:26      Est. Close Date     19/01/2018      16/02/2018
```

Completely stuck on this, any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Could you add your expected output?

Comment: @Milton - "My issue here is the revenue field" There is no field named revenue in your dataset.
Also, please have a look at the `DISTINCT` keyword and let us know if you have a problem from there. https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/distinct.php

Comment: Brilliant, all suggestions work perfectly. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery to achieve this

```
SELECT timeStamp, fieldValue,prevValue,newValue FROM 
    (SELECT timeStamp, fieldValue,prevValue,newValue,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY timeStamp, fieldValue, prevValue, 
            newValue ORDER BY timestamp) as rownum ) AS T1
WHERE T1.rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte as (
      SELECT *,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY timeStamp, fieldValue, prevValue) as rn
      FROM YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: or more succinctly, just a subquery `select * from (select ... from mytable) where rn = 1`

Comment: @Bohemian I like my cte :) . Anyway Hadi did it with a subquery so we are cover

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT timeStamp,
       fieldValue,
       prevValue,
       newValue,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY timeStamp, fieldValue, prevValue, newValue ORDER BY timeStamp) AS RowNumb
    FROM TableName
    WHERE fieldValue = 'Revenue'
)
SELECT timeStamp,
       fieldValue,
       prevValue,
       newValue
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE RowNumb = 1
UNION
SELECT timeStamp,
       fieldValue,
       prevValue,
       newValue
    FROM TableName
    WHERE fieldValue != 'Revenue'
```